# MySql Join tables based on field value

Tags: mysql, join

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.*, u.*
FROM
  posts AS p 
  IF(p.status = 1) 
  LEFT JOIN users AS u 
    ON u.id = p.user_id 
    ELSE 
  LEFT JOIN pusers AS u 
    ON u.id = p.user_id 
WHERE p.id = 10 ;
```

Based on post status being true/false join users/pusers table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (case when p.status = 1 then u.col1 else pu.col1 end) as col1
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     users u 
     ON u.id = p.user_id and p.status = 1 LEFT JOIN
     pusers AS pu 
     ON pu.id = p.user_id and p.status <> 1
WHERE p.id = 10 ;
```

In other words, you can join both tables and use the values from the table, based on the condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'u.col1' in 'field list' [code: 42S22]"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just needed a valid column name. It works perfect . Thanks.